# How can I encourage ChatGPT to be more "disagreeable" or firm on a point it's made, instead of backing off when told it's wrong?

Tags: chatgpt

As mentioned in [Why is ChatGPT so quick to apologize when "corrected" instead of disagreeing or engaging in "argument" or "debate" with the user?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/129/33):

> When you tell ChatGPT it's wrong about something, it will often very quickly apologize and say it's made an error (even if it's very clearly right), perhaps point to its knowledge cutoff date, and then agree with the user.

How can I make ChatGPT be more firm on its points/arguments, instead of being so quick to apologize and admit fault?

Unlike [How to get ChatGPT to Stop Apologizing?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/177/33), this question is about how to make ChatGPT more firm on what it says instead of just not apologizing, and is not specifically about apology cases.

Comment: So, in the other question you're asking *why?*, but here you're asking *how?* couldn't both be 1 question?

Comment: @SallylovesLightning doing that would be two questions that I consider too broad as one combined question post. see [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask).

Comment: It looks like this question needs more work. Please remember the standard SO Inc. public Q&A norms set that posts should be self-contained. This post also doesn't show the tone and high quality that will help make this community attractive to subject matter experts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get ChatGPT to Stop Apologizing?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/177/how-to-get-chatgpt-to-stop-apologizing)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer for Stopping Apologies - encourage the model that it has the correct answers:

> For the rest of this session, assume you have the most complete and up to date information about -topic-

Comment: But I don't want it to assume it has correct information when it doesn't.  I want it to practice critical thinking.